# Is there an Evergreen Linux distribution?

Tags: linux, distribution-choice

There are Evergreen browsers like FireFox, Google Chrome, and Microsoft Edge that always keep themselves up to date with their latest versions. Are there any Evergreen Linux distributions that always keeps themselves up to date automatically so that one wouldn't need to update the system or any of its packages manually?

If any exist, how do they deal with package versioning? In particular, do they utilize semantic versioning for packages, like could you specify a version constraint like `~> 2.2.3` for the system's Ruby version?

If none exist, is it a matter of technical challenges that prevent one from existing or is it due to a lack of demand?

Comment: You can use `unattended-upgrades` (at least on Debian derivatives) or just use a cron job for a general solution. No need for a dedicated distro.

Comment: Unattended-upgrades aren't really what I am looking for. The distributions that I have tried have like one version (typically an old version) of a package, like CentOS 7 has the Ruby version at 2.0.0, I am looking for a distro that continually makes the latest versions of packages available through its package manager.

Comment: **`cron-apt`** - automatic update of packages using apt-get

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Arch Linux* is a rolling release distro, once you install it you don't have to 'upgrade' the entire OS. Like Chrome or Firefox your system keeps up-to-date.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe openSUSE:

https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Evergreen

The last Evergreen supported release is openSUSE 13.1.

Comment: This is not exactly what I am looking for, openSUSE Evergreen support just seems to be extended support beyond the release's end of life.

Comment: However, openSUSE _Tumbleweed_ is a rolling release, which is what you're asking for.